# Running native code for armeabi on arm64

Tags: android, android-ndk

I want to use javacv lib from bytedeco on Android. But it only has precompiled native binaries for armeabi. When I try to run it on arm64-v8a phone like Samsung S7, there is the following error:

```
[/data/app/com.app-1/lib/arm64, /system/fake-libs64, /data/app/com.app-1/base.apk!/lib/arm64-v8a, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]] couldn't find "libjniopencv_core.so"
```

How to overcome this?

Comment: Looks like your app contains at least one native library for arm64-v8a. In that case you have 2 options: either remove all arm64-v8a libraries, or provide arm64-v8a versions of all libraries.

Comment: So, I should remove all alternative versions except armeabi?

Comment: Yes. The OS will check if your app contains any native libraries for the device's primary ABI, and if so it expects **all** native libraries in your app to be available for that ABI. If no libraries at all are provided for the primary ABI, it tries the same thing for the device's secondary ABI(s). So you cannot e.g. have libX and libY for armeabi but only libX for arm64-v8a, because that would fail on a 64-bit device.

Comment: Check out my repo: https://github.com/skanti/Android-Manual-Build-Command-Line. I might have what you need.